# MongoDB update array in multiple nested document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections like the following

```
{
   _id: 1
   rooms:[{
      _id: 1,
      doors: [{
          _id: 1,
          name: 'kitchen',
          color: 'green'
      },{
          _id:2,
          name: 'bathroom',
          color: 'red'
      }] 
   }]
}
```

I want to update the whole content of specific door by id.

I try this code but it not work.

```
db.collections.update({_id:1, "rooms._id":1, "rooms.doors._id":2}, {$set: {rooms.$.doors.$: {_id:2, name: 'balcony', color:'yellow'}}}
```

If I use "rooms.$.doors.0", it will always update the first door in array.

```
db.collections.update({_id:1, "rooms._id":1, "rooms.doors._id":2}, {$set: {rooms.$.doors.0: {_id:2, name: 'balcony', color:'yellow'}}}
```

Anyone can help?.

Thank you for your looking.

Comment: Per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays, "The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value."

Comment: Yes, I think I should not design database with nesting multiple array like that. Thanks Jstell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to avoid nesting multiple array like that. it's too troublesome if you wish to update. In previous version of mongodb, [this guide](https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays) still works, apparently not in latest version of mongodb. Just for fun, if you read the guide, imagine, how many $$ we need to update another nested array.

you can try aggregation, but I think it is easier to bring the the whole document with {_id:1} to server, replace the whole rooms_array and save it.

```
   db.collections.find({_id:1}).exec((err, house)=>{
         var rooms = house.rooms.map((r)=> {
            return r.doors.map((d) => {
                if(r._id === 1 && d._id === 2){
                   return  {_id:2, name: 'balcony', color:'yellow'}
                }
                else{
                     return d
                }
            })
         })
         house.rooms = rooms
         house.save()
   })
```

alternative, perhaps you can do object reference for doors. Instead another document, just include ObjectId that refers to the doors. This door will be another new collection.

Comment: Thanks vdj4y for helping